# Trouble with IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

Link: http://new.floorbase.nl

Problem: With the first load in IE9, the canvas positions aren't right. But after opening console or change mode, its position is correct.

## First start screen

[image]

## After opening console or change mode

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `console.log` statements in your js file. IE natively doesn't understand `console.log` because it doesn't have a console and hence the javascript breaks. But when the console is invoked(I am guessing developer tools) the console.log statements are run.

All you have to do is remove or comment out the `console.log` statements.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Never thought that console.log might be the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, it happens because IE by default renders a page in quirks mode.

```
quirks mode refers to a technique used by some web browsers for the sake of 
maintaining backward compatibility with web pages designed for older browsers, 
instead of strictly complying with W3C and IETF standards in standards mode.
```

If you want to use the higher IE version then add the following line into your `<head>` tags

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```